# Where to load data in a React/Redux/Routerv4 app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I am working on an app that functions almost entirely on the following route: `/task/:taskId` and there is nothing to render at the `/` route. Instead when you launch the app it should redirect to a task. Much like when you open slack and you are in a channel. Not on some page that says please select a channel. I cannot figure out where I'm suppose to load the tasks from the database.

Right now, I have a component that loads at `/` and in its `componentDidMount` method, I load the tasks from the database. Once the tasks are loaded, I do a `history.push` to redirect to the first task in the array of tasks from the database.

This all works great until I get redirected to a specific task and then refresh the page. That is, if I'm at `/task/foobar` and I refresh the page, the app doesn't load anything because tasks is only loaded from the database at `/`.

So what is the proper way to make sure that my data is loaded no matter which page I'm on?

EDIT - Adding some code for reference:

**/routes.js** - / uses Master.js and /task/:taskId uses TaskPage.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router';
import App from './containers/App';
import Master from './containers/Master';
import TaskPage from './containers/TaskPage';

export default () => (
  <App>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Master} />
      <Route path="/task/:taskId" component={TaskPage} />
    </Switch>
  </App>
);
```

**/containers/Master.js** - loadTasks is action creator that passes tasks data to tasks reducer. Also returns promise that resolves to the tasks data once loaded from local nedb database.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { loadTasks } from '../actions/tasks';

class Master extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData() {
    this.props.loadTasks()
    .then(tasks => {
      const id = tasks[Object.keys(tasks)[0]]._id;
      this.props.history.push(`/task/${id}`);
      return true;
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log('ERROR', e);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (props, ownProps) => ({
  taskId: ownProps.taskId
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  loadTasks
})(Master);
```

**/containers/TaskPage.js** - Not much to see here. Just passing props to wrapped component Task which renders just fine as long as the app loads / first. If you hit /task/:taskId directly, nothing loads because the tasks data in the database only gets loaded to the redux store at /

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Task from '../components/Task';

const mapStateToProps = ({ tasks }, { match: { params: { taskId } } }) => ({
  tasks,
  taskId
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Task);
```

Comment: When you navigate to a group using groupId, are you making a service call to fetch the group with that id?

Comment: @Dev This is a very small electron application using NEDB with minimal data, so I just load all of the groups at once stored by ID. So right now, the only database load happens at `/` where that data is then loaded into the redux store. When you go to a group using groupId it just pulls the groups data from the redux store. No new db fetch necessary.

Comment: So, in componentDidMount of group component, you can filter out the group from groups which you might have maintained in store/state, and render based on the filtered data.

Comment: This seems like a router issue. Where have you hosted your app? If it is in surge you'll need to add 200.html page. Basically what you want is for the '/' path to load no matter what url is typed. Then the browser will forward the url to the router, which will mount the right component according to the url.

Comment: If you provide further details like where you have hosted your app, we might be able to help you.

Comment: @YasserHussain unfortunately it is an electron app that I cannot make public. That said, I will update my question to include some pieces of code.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** - I have removed my old answers in favor of what I think is a better approach based on some digging I've done.

I've seen a few things from Dan Abramov in a few places that make me think he'd do the data fetching inside of the component (not container) and he would use the componentDidMount lifecycle method to do so. The only piece I am not certain about is how best to decide if the app should display a loading status.

In Dan's and others' examples, they just check to see if state.loading is false and if state.items.length is 0. This only works if you always expect items to have data. But in my case, when you first launch the app, you will have no data in it so checking for 0 length doesn't really work. Instead I've added an initLoad property to the state.

I'm open to other ways of handling this if there are better methods.

**routes.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router';
import App from './containers/App';
import TaskPage from './containers/TaskPage';

export default () => (
  <App>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={TaskPage} />
      <Route path="/task/:taskId" component={TaskPage} />
    </Switch>
  </App>
);
```

**TaskPage.js**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

import { loadTasks } from '../actions/tasks';

import Task from '../components/Task';

const mapStateToProps = ({ tasks }, { match: { params: { taskId } } }) => ({
  tasks,
  taskId,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  loadTasks: () => dispatch(loadTasks())
});

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Task));
```

**Task.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import type { tasksType } from '../reducers/tasks';

import SidebarContainer from '../containers/SidebarContainer';

class Task extends Component {
  props: {
    loadTasks: () => any,
    initForm: () => any,
    taskId: string,
    tasks: tasksType,
    history: any
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData() {
    this.props.loadTasks()
    .then(tasks => {
      const taskId = this.props.taskId;

      if (!taskId) {
        const id = tasks[Object.keys(tasks)[0]]._id;
        this.props.history.push(`/task/${id}`);
      }

      return true;
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log('ERROR', e);
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { tasks, taskId, initForm } = this.props;

    if (!tasks.initLoad || (tasks.loading && Object.keys(tasks.items).length < 1)) {
      return <div>Loading</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div id="wrapper">
        <SidebarContainer taskId={taskId} />
        <div id="main">
          <div id="group-details">
            {tasks.initLoad && Object.keys(tasks.items).length > 0 ?
              (<div>Task details would go here...</div>) :
              (<div>Please create a task</div>)
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Task;
```